# Entity Relationship with JoinColumn

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Hi everyone I have a problem with @JoinColumn. In my case I just want to reach Entities with @JoinColumn(Foreign Key) not using @OneToMany or @ManyToOne beacue these 2 annotation
pretends to have a entity in it.

Example :

**Product Entity :**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class
Product extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price", length = 10, nullable = false)
    private Double price;

    @Column(name = "expiration_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime expirationDate;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "product_status", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private ProductStatus productStatus = ProductStatus.ACTIVE;

    @JoinColumn(name = "categoryId")
    private Long categoryId;

}
```

**Category Entity :**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;

}
```

---

As can be seen I use categoryId in ProductEntity with type Long as Foreign Key with @JoinColumn annotation.

At my saveProduct(POST) process I just enter categoryId for saveProduct.

```
{
  "name": "Fruit",
  "price": 13.40,
  "expirationDate": "2024-04-07T00:05:49.713Z",
  "description": "Apple",
  "categoryId": 5
}
```

And my saveCategory body just use String name

```
{
  "name": "Fruit"
}
```

Before my save operations I am using DTO and Requests with mapstruct to convert Request to Entity after that convert to Entity to DTO

**ProductMapper :**

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface ProductMapper {

    ProductMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ProductMapper.class);

    Product convertToProduct(ProductSaveRequest request);

    ProductDTO convertToProductDTO(Product product);

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    void updateProductFields(@MappingTarget Product product, ProductUpdateRequest request);


}
```

**Category Mapper :**

```
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface CategoryMapper {

    CategoryMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CategoryMapper.class);

    Category convertToCategory(CategorySaveRequest request);

    CategoryDTO convertToCategoryDTO(Category category);

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    void updateCategoryFields(@MappingTarget Category category, CategoryUpdateRequest request);
}
```

**ProductDTO :**

```
public record ProductDTO(Long id,
                         String name,
                         Double price,
                         LocalDateTime expirationDate,
                         String description,
                         ProductStatus productStatus,
                         Long categoryId) {
}
```

**CategoryDTO :**

```
public record CategoryDTO(Long id,
                              String name) {
    }
```

**ProductSaveRequest :**

```
public record ProductSaveRequest(String name,
                                 Double price,
                                 LocalDateTime expirationDate,
                                 String description,
                                 Long categoryId) {
}
```

**CategorySaveRequest :**

```
public record CategorySaveRequest(String name) {

}
```

**Problem Notice :**

When I save Category I just give the name not Product or ProductList or ProductId because it doesn't make no sense for case.

Well all of the end my problem is I have a get request(GET) with named getProductsWithCategoryId It should return products with categoryId{id} as a list. How can I reach or use JoinColumn in Category or should I ? or when I use JoinColumn in Category Entity with private Long productId; how can I reach products in categoryService and return a List ?